# Defining a long string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple problem that I just can't seem to figure out.  In the code below I get an error (test_str is not defined) because the line defining "var str=" is spread across two lines.  After the word "fox" there is a CR LF and I guess my javascript engine in my browser thinks I want a new statement there.  Now of course in this example I can simply get rid of the carriage return and put it all on one line to fix it.  But my real intent is for a much longer string in some production code which I don't really want to mess with deleting all those CR LF's.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test_str() {
  str = "  The quick brown 
  fox jumped over the log.";
  alert(str);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='test_str();'>Test String</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a `\` at the end of each line still in the string

```
str = "  The quick brown \  // <---
fox jumped over the log.";
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do is to add a `\` at the end of the lines:

```
function test_str() {
  str = "  The quick brown \
  fox jumped over the log.";
  alert(str);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/C9eea/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `\r\n` in your string to represent CR LF :

```
str = "The quick brown\r\nfox jumped over the log.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = " the quick brown fox\r\n" + 
  "fox jumped over the lazy dog";
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals can't span multiple lines in JavaScript. You'll need to either explicitly continue each line onto the next:

```
var foo = "The quick brown fox\
 jumped over the lazy\
 dog";
```

Or concatenate string literals:

```
var foo = "The quick brown fox " +
          "jumped over the lazy " +
          "dog";
```

I personally prefer the latter, as you'll be able to indent it more reasonably without as much regard to whitespace within the string, since

```
var foo = "asdf \
           bar";
```

would result in a string like "asdf           bar".

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the newline literal,

```
str = "  The quick brown \
      fox jumped over the log.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define multi line strings is to use an Array and join them. This allows you to easily define a new line character (`\n\r`) for each line assuming you store lines by Array index (`""` for no character seperation between lines). For instance below will create the following string:

> The quick brown
>   fox jumped over the log.

```
str = ["  The quick brown ",
  "fox jumped over the log."].join("\n\r");//each line should be a new line
```